# JPA Criteria seems to ignore join on condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, criteria

I've a **User** and **Contact** entities in my app and I need to every user can add some private comment about every contact and that comment must be available only for that user. So I create new entity - **PrivateInfo**. Here's the code.

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String login;

// other fields
}
```

Contact class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Contact implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "contact")
private Set<PrivateInfo> privateInfo;

// etc.
}
```

PrivateInfo class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "private_info")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PrivateInfo implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private PrivateInfoKey pk;
@Column(name = "additional_info")
private String additionalInfo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapsId("contactId")
private Contact contact;

}

@Embeddable
public class PrivateInfoKey implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "contact_id")
private Long contactId;
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

}
```

I'm using Spring Data repositories with **JpaSpecificationExecutor** for querying so here's my attempt to write specification for getting all contacts with private info for specific user.

```
public static Specification<Contact> withPrivateInfo(final long userId) {
    return new Specification<Contact>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            Join<Contact, PrivateInfo> joinPrivateInfo = root.join(Contact_.privateInfo, JoinType.LEFT);
            joinPrivateInfo.on(cb.equal(
                  joinPrivateInfo.get(PrivateInfo_.pk).get(PrivateInfoKey_.userId), userId
            ));

            return cb.conjunction();   // translates in sql like '... where 1 = 1'
        }
    };
}
```

However, when I call

```
 contactRepository.findAll(withPrivateInfo(1));
```

I'm receiving contacts and each of them contains in privateInfo field all users information about this contact (not only for user with id = 1, as expected). Seems like *join on* condition ignored.

Any suggestions how to achieve my goal? Maybe with another entities structure. Is this possible with JPA/Criteria?